# How can I change the QGraphicView selected Item color

Tags: c++, qt, colors

How can I change `QGraphicView` selected item color.In this code which can select items form `QGraphicView` and delete and also able to disable item moving.How can I change the color of selected Item.

```
void Widget::on_btnDelete_clicked()
{
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item,ui->graphicsView->scene()->selectedItems()) {
       delete item;
    }
}

void Widget::on_btnMoveDis_clicked()
{
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item,ui->graphicsView->scene()->selectedItems()) {
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable,false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I suggest you to read `QGraphicsView` examples and docs carefully , I recommend [Diagram Scene Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) and [Elastic Nodes Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html) as starting point. Because QGraphicsView frame work is smart if you use it smart otherwise you may pay penalties in **performance**.

And now your question :

whole answer is related to `qgraphicsitem_cast`, how to use it?

First let me provide some initializations look code below at first I add three rectangles to scene and set their flags.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnInit_clicked()
{
    QColor color = Qt::red;
    QBrush brush = Qt::SolidPattern;
    brush.setColor(color);
    QRect  * rectObject = new QRect(QPoint(0,0) , QSize(20,20));
    scene.addRect(*rectObject , color, brush);

    rectObject = new QRect(QPoint(0,30) , QSize(20,20));
    color = Qt::green;
    brush.setColor(color);
    scene.addRect(*rectObject , color, brush);

    rectObject = new QRect(QPoint(0,60) , QSize(20,20));
    color = Qt::blue;
    brush.setColor(color);
    scene.addRect(*rectObject , color, brush);

    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item,ui->graphicsView->scene()->items()) {
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable , true);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable , true);
    }
}
```

I have set `ItemIsMovable` and `ItemIsSelectable` flags so for items could be selectable.

and now change color of selected item.

```
 void MainWindow::on_btnSelectItem_clicked()
    {
        foreach (QGraphicsItem *item,  ui->graphicsView->scene()->selectedItems())
        {
            QGraphicsRectItem *rect = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem *>(item);
            if (!rect)
                continue;

            QBrush br(Qt::SolidPattern);
            br.setColor(Qt::black);
            rect->setBrush(br);
            rect->update();
        }
   }
```

I use `QGraphicsRectItem` to cast rectangular objects that i added to scene before. If you want to learn more on use `qgraphicsitem` read Elastic Nodes Example.

Comment: @Rooter if you want provide me your email address to send whole test project

Comment: @Rooter It's better to ask a new question for resize of QGraphicsView

Comment: Thank you very much sir,I'll do so,thanks for your mail :)

Comment: I posted it as a new question sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864465/how-can-i-re-size-the-qgraphicitem-using-mouse